# LINQ-запросы из связанных таблиц для MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Дано три таблицы:
Students ключ Id
Rates ключи StudentId, DisciplineId
Disciplines ключ Id

То есть студентов может быть много, у каждого много предметов и оценок.
Предмет один но у него может быть много оценок у разных студентов.

В MSSMS сочинил запрос:

```
select Name, SurName, SUM(Rates.Rate) as 'rate'
from Students join Rates on Students.id = Rates.StudentId
group by Students.Name, Students.SurName
```

Он выводит табличку, которую мне нужно вывести в ASP.NET MVC.
Но перевести ее в язык Linq не выходит.

Код:

```
    var rates = db.Rates.Include(s => s.Students)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Students.Id, x => x.Rate)
        .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Rate = x.Sum() });

    ViewBag.SR = rates.ToList();
```

Код View:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.SR)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Что выводит мой код:

[image: Что выводит мой код]

Считать считает, но поделить это на таблицу или сделать вид как в MSSMS не выходит. Что делаю не так?

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SurName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Disciplines (
    dId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Discipline varchar(50) NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE Rates (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DisciplineId int REFERENCES Disciplines (dId),
    StudentId int REFERENCES Students (Id),
    Rate int
);

INSERT INTO Disciplines (Discipline) VALUES ('ASP.NET')
INSERT INTO Disciplines (Discipline) VALUES ('ADO.NET')

INSERT INTO Students (Name, SurName) VALUES ('Ivan', 'Ivanov')
INSERT INTO Students (Name, SurName) VALUES ('Petr', 'Petrov')

INSERT INTO Rates (DisciplineId, StudentId, Rate) VALUES (1, 1, 5)
INSERT INTO Rates (DisciplineId, StudentId, Rate) VALUES (1, 2, 4)
INSERT INTO Rates (DisciplineId, StudentId, Rate) VALUES (2, 1, 4)
INSERT INTO Rates (DisciplineId, StudentId, Rate) VALUES (2, 2, 5)
```

Код из DBFirst:

```
    public partial class Model1 : DbContext
        {
            public Model1()
                : base("name=Model1")
            {
            }
    
            public virtual DbSet<Disciplines> Disciplines { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Rates> Rates { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Students> Students { get; set; }
           
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Disciplines>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.Rates)
                    .WithOptional(e => e.Disciplines)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.DisciplineId);
    
                modelBuilder.Entity<Students>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.Rates)
                    .WithOptional(e => e.Students)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.StudentId);
            }
        }

 public partial class Disciplines
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Disciplines()
        {
            this.Rates = new HashSet<Rates>();
        }
    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Discipline { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Rates> Rates { get; set; }
    }
 public partial class Rates
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DisciplineId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StudentId { get; set; }
        public int Rate { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Disciplines Disciplines { get; set; }
        public virtual Students Students { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Students
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Students()
        {
            this.Rates = new HashSet<Rates>();
        }
    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Rates> Rates { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Linq2sql - это очень древняя ORM. Вы действительно её используете? Или всё таки Entity Framework (Core)? И укажите точную версию.

Comment: Вместо анонимного типа используйте класс-модель.

Comment: `group by Students.Name, Students.SurName` vs `.GroupBy(x => x.Students.Id, x => x.Rate)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Framework 4.8, Entity 6

Comment: Если вы хотите получить ответ, то не молчите, как партизан на допросе. Приведите код сущностей и код заполнения таблиц. Тут делов на несколько минут для отвечающего, если бы эти данные были. Но никому неохота вручную создавать то, что у вас уже есть. Вам делов на несколько секунд скопипастить код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо за ответ, действительно все заработало, упустил из виду что нужно делать отдельную модель под данный функционал.
В вашем коде " foreach (StudentRateModel item in ViewBag.SR)" остается странным момент что название модели стоит перед item. Я заменил на var.  Запрос по итогу получился конечно сложный. Запрос создания БД SQL добавил в первоначальный вопрос.

Comment: Вы используете подход Database First? Я бы предпочёл увидеть C#-код сущностей.

Comment: `ViewBag` - это `dynamic`. И его свойства тоже имеют тип `dynamic`. Поэтому, когда вы используете `var`, это приводит к поиску свойств `Name`, `Surname`, `Rate` в рантайме, что медленно. И интеллисенс не работает. Поэтому верните явное указание типа - это удобнее и быстрее. PS: название типа (модели) всегда стоит перед именем переменной, это синтаксис C#.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov обновил в заголовке код. Да использую Базу данных в начале. Так мне проще создать продумать БД в студии.

Таким образом мне в начале страницы View не нужно указывать [at]model  StudentRateModel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы вы опубликовали код ваших сущностей и пример заполнения таблиц данными, то давно бы получили ответ. Ведь никому неохота вручную набивать тот код, который у вас уже есть.

Для начала, создадим модель, которая будет содержат нужные данные:

```
public class StudentRateModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }
}
```

Навскидку, запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
var rates = db.Rates
    .Include(s => s.Students)
    .GroupBy(
        x => x.Students,
        (x, y) => new { Student = x, Sum = y.Sum(r => r.Rate) })
    .Select(x => new StudentRateModel
    {
        Name = x.Student.Name,
        Surname = x.Student.Surname,
        Rate = x.Sum
    });
```

Естественно, я его не проверял. Если приведёте необходимый код, я его протестирую.

Код во View:

```
<table class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (StudentRateModel item in ViewBag.SR)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Surname</td>
            <td>@item.Rate</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```